# Change font color of Today's date with black in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to change font color of Todays date with "Black" which is set as Maximum dat in UIDatepicker in Iphone ??

Is It Possible??

Thank You

Comment: Yes, it's indeed possible. Your welcome.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you even tried looking up all the relevant parts, such as UIDatePicker and font color?

Comment: Ya i have tried to add label to row but it change color of all rows in date picker??

Comment: What's the question? What did you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)pickerValueChanged:(id)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;

        if ([self.datePicker.date compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending) {

            datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: you also got sample code from here http://code4app.net/ios/Local-Notifier/4fb5e7c06803fa3a7f000000